# Parse: Write Cloud Code on Parse Server

Tags: angular, parse-platform, ionic3, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am using Parse Server as BaaS for my application written with Ionic 3 and Angular 4. I have used to write my queries on Client Side and store with a provider the results locally to consume them by the users.

Now I have been advised to run the queries (and maybe the localstorage functions ???) on the Server with Cloud Code.

So my question is how to write them on the Server of Parse and what about the concept of the localstorage

Here is my search.ts to make the query and consume the results from localstorage

```
initializeItems() {
  this.users= this.localdata.tmpusers;
}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localdata: localData) {
  this.searchControl = new FormControl;
  this.query.find().then(data => {
  this.tmp = data; 
  console.log(this.tmp);
  this.localdata.setUsers(this.tmp);

  this.users = this.localdata.tmpusers;
  console.log (this.users);
  })
 }
```

and here is my localdata.ts to save the results from the query and consume them

```
setUsers (users){
    window.localStorage.users_data = JSON.stringify(users);
}
getUsers(){
   return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.users_data || '[]');
}

tmpusers = this.getUsers();
constructor(){
    this.tmpusers.sort(function(a, b) {
        var nameA = a.username.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        var nameB = b.username.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }

        // names must be equal
        return 0;
      });
}
```

So how should I proceed with Cloud Code and localstorage for the best performance?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use native [**storage**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) module here.

Then it is like this: (This is just an example from the doc.Please convert it to your use case)

```
 // set a key/value
  storage.set('name', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
```

Comment: How I should write my query on Parse Server on Cloud Code?and save the results with native storage?Andhow can I call the function of Cloud Code?

Comment: You need to use `providers` for that. See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bATjiu9myvI

Comment: yes of course I know about providers, how to call the function of the Server Side I do not know

Comment: Is that `Rest API`?

Comment: My goal is to get a user list from the from the database (MongoDB) on my Parse Server. The best practice as i have understand is to create the query on Cloud Code and then consume it from client side (Ionic 3) through a provider

Comment: Yes, You can do that way.

Comment: Yes sure, the point is that i do not know how to call it from Ionic 3 and typescript

Comment: Hope this helps to you: https://www.udemy.com/getting-started-with-ionic-2-and-parse-server/#curriculum